# How to convert a list of object to a tree

Tags: javascript, list, tree

I have a data like this:

```
[
    {
        ID: 1,
        Title: 't1',
        parentID: null,
    },
    {
        ID: 2,
        Title: 't2',
        parentID: null,
    },
    {
        ID: 50,
        Title: 'tt',
        parentID: 2,
    },
    {
        ID: 30,
        Title: 'ct',
        parentID: 2,
    },    
    {
        ID: 6,
        Title: 'cyt',
        parentID: 50,
    }
]
```

I want to convert the list above to a tree like structure, which each object has a `children` and this `child-parent` relationship is defined in the list using a `parentID`, if the `parentID` is `null` it means the object doesn't have any parent

```
[
    {
        ID: 1,
        Title: 't1',
        parentID: null,
    },
    {
        ID: 2,
        Title: 't2',
        parentID: null,
        children: [
            {
                ID: 50,
                Title: 'tt',
                parentID: 2,
                children: [
                    {
                        ID: 6,
                        Title: 'cyt',
                        parentID: 50,
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                ID: 30,
                Title: 'ct',
                parentID: 2,
            }, 
        ]
    }
]
```

I am looking for a good way to do this which is both optimal and doesn't require lots of looping, since the objects might grow in number.

Comment: Please search before asking questions.

Comment: @str I did, i guess i was looking for the wrong keyword, i searched for `list to tree`

Comment: Fair enough to close this, but out of curiosity I looked through all answers on the three referenced issues and apparently only a *single one* (which is not one of the accepted answers) actually has the same (optimal) runtime complexity, most are O(n^2) or the like. That's sobering...

Answer (score 0):

You can first create a mapping of IDs to objects, and then in one pass assign all children based on this mapping. Runtime complexity O(n).

```js
var data = [
    {
        ID: 1,
        Title: 't1',
        parentID: null,
    },
    {
        ID: 2,
        Title: 't2',
        parentID: null,
    },
    {
        ID: 50,
        Title: 'tt',
        parentID: 2,
    },
    {
        ID: 30,
        Title: 'ct',
        parentID: 2,
    },    
    {
        ID: 6,
        Title: 'cyt',
        parentID: 50,
    }
] ;

const map = {};
for (let i= 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  map[data[i].ID] = data[i];
}

for (let i= 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  const parent = map[data[i].parentID];
  if (parent) {
    if (parent.children == null) {
      parent.children = [data[i]];
    } else {
      parent.children.push(data[i]);
    }
  }
}

console.log(data.filter(e => e.parentID == null));
```

Comment: @Kobe not really rocket science. I added a working sample, even though I'm not sure if this is indeed the right thing to do since this sounds like homework...